# How can I fix 'failed calling webhook "webhook.cert-manager.io"'?

Tags: kubernetes, k3s, cert-manager

I'm trying to set up a K3s cluster. When I had a single master and agent setup cert-manager had no issues. Now I'm trying a 2 master setup with embedded etcd. I opened TCP ports `6443` and `2379-2380` for both VMs and did the following:

```
VM1: curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | sh -s server --token TOKEN --cluster-init
VM2: curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | sh -s server --token TOKEN --server https://MASTER_IP:6443
```

```
# k3s kubectl get nodes
NAME  STATUS   ROLES                       AGE    VERSION
VM1   Ready    control-plane,etcd,master   130m   v1.22.7+k3s1
VM2   Ready    control-plane,etcd,master   128m   v1.22.7+k3s1
```

Installing cert-manager works fine:

```
# k3s kubectl apply -f https://github.com/cert-manager/cert-manager/releases/download/v1.8.0/cert-manager.yaml
# k3s kubectl get pods --namespace cert-manager
NAME                                       READY   STATUS
cert-manager-b4d6fd99b-c6fpc               1/1     Running
cert-manager-cainjector-74bfccdfdf-gtmrd   1/1     Running
cert-manager-webhook-65b766b5f8-brb76      1/1     Running
```

My manifest has the following definition:

```yaml
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: info@example.org
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-account-key
    solvers:
    - selector: {}
      http01:
        ingress: {}
```

Which results in the following error:

```
# k3s kubectl apply -f manifest.yaml
Error from server (InternalError): error when creating "manifest.yaml": Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "webhook.cert-manager.io": failed to call webhook: Post "https://cert-manager-webhook.cert-manager.svc:443/mutate?timeout=10s": context deadline exceeded
```

I tried disabling both firewalls, waiting a day, reset and re-setup, but the error persists. Google hasn't been much help either. The little info I can find goes over my head for the most part and no tutorial seems to do any extra steps.

Comment: From what you've told us, you have a 2 nodes cluster, with no SDN. Check https://projectcalico.docs.tigera.io/getting-started/kubernetes/k3s/multi-node-install . Also: while I'm not familiar with k3s, having 2 control plane nodes sounds weird, are they both hosting etcd? If so: you should go with 3 nodes. A 2 nodes etcd cluster would not tolerate any failure.

Answer (score 2):

A good starting point for troubleshooting issues with the webhook can be found int the [docs](https://cert-manager.io/docs/concepts/webhook/#known-problems-and-solutions), e.g. there is a section for [problems on GKE private clusters](https://cert-manager.io/docs/concepts/webhook/#known-problems-and-solutions).

In my case, however, this didn't really solve the problem. For me the issue was that when I played around with `cert-manager` I happen to install and uninstall it multiple times. It turned out that just removing the namespace, e.g. `kubectl delete namespace cert-manager` didn't remove the webhooks and other non-obvious resources.

Following the official guide for [uninstalling cert-manager](https://cert-manager.io/v1.2-docs/installation/uninstall/kubernetes/) and applying the manifests again solved the issue.

Comment: Many thanks, I spent ages on this before you showed me the way.  Failed to uninstall properly.  I just wiped my test cluster and rebuilt.

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the proper ingress class name in your Cluster Issuer, like this:

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: info@example.org
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-account-key
    solvers:
    - http01:
        ingress:
          class: nginx
```

Also, make sure that you have the cert manager annotation and the tls secret name specified in your Ingress like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
    annotations:
      cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt
...
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - domain.com
      secretName: letsencrypt-account-key
```

Comment: Big thanks! I changed the name of my ingress service, but copied the `incress.class` from the example.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to make the installation and these 2 ways are to be deleted/uninstalled the same way they were installed.

**If you installed using this link:**
*kubectl apply -f https://github.com/cert-manager/cert-manager/releases/download/vX.Y.Z/cert-manager.yaml*

**Delete using this:**
*kubectl delete -f https://github.com/cert-manager/cert-manager/releases/download/vX.Y.Z/cert-manager.yaml*

**If you installed using this link:**
*kubectl apply -f https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/releases/download/vX.Y.Z/cert-manager.yaml*

**Delete using this:**
*kubectl apply -f https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/releases/download/vX.Y.Z/cert-manager.yaml*

If you are experiencing terminating state, run:
**kubectl delete apiservice v1beta1.webhook.cert-manager.io**

source: https://cert-manager.io/v1.2-docs/installation/uninstall/kubernetes/

Personally, I go as far as checking the node tied to the certificate and recycle or delete it because I have set the pool to autoscale.

Then, follow the instruction on this page to assist you make a successful installation:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nginx-ingress-with-cert-manager-on-digitalocean-kubernetes

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while installing Eclipse Che on minikube. I just reran the command and this time the certs worked!

Worth trying once.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue, which generated the following error message:

```
Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "webhook.cert-manager.io": failed to call webhook: Post "https://cert-manager-webhook.cert-manager.svc:443/mutate?timeout=10s": context deadline exceeded
```

Upon investigation, I determined that the root cause was a DNS problem within the cluster. To confirm this, I initiated an Alpine pod and executed a ping command, which resulted in a failure when attempting to ping "google.com."

To resolve the issue, I needed to correct the CoreDNS configuration map. In my case, the problem stemmed from an incorrect cluster domain, which was originally set to `<wrong-domain>.at`.

**Here's how I fixed it:**

I edited the CoreDNS configuration map to replace `<wrong-domain>.a`t with the correct cluster domain.

```
# kubectl -n kube-system get configmaps/coredns -o yaml

apiVersion: v1
data:
  Corefile: |-
    .:53 {
        errors
        health {
            lameduck 5s
        }
        ready
        log . {
            class error
        }
        prometheus :9153

        kubernetes <wrong-domain>.at in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
            pods insecure
            fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
        }
        forward . /etc/resolv.conf
        cache 30
        loop
        reload
        loadbalance
    }
kind: ConfigMap
```

Additionally, it's worth mentioning that the issue might also be related to IPv6. If you're using IPv6, ensure that the network where the cluster is deployed supports IPv6 as well.

Answer (score 0):

if you encounter the problem and you are running on aws eks you can solve it with setting hostNetwork to true like [here](https://AWS%20EKS%20When%20using%20a%20custom%20CNI%20(such%20as%20Weave%20or%20Calico)%20on%20EKS,%20the%20webhook%20cannot%20be%20reached%20by%20cert-manager.%20This%20happens%20because%20the%20control%20plane%20cannot%20be%20configured%20to%20run%20on%20a%20custom%20CNI%20on%20EKS,%20so%20the%20CNIs%20differ%20between%20control%20plane%20and%20worker%20nodes.%20%20To%20address%20this,%20the%20webhook%20can%20be%20run%20in%20the%20host%20network%20so%20it%20can%20be%20reached%20by%20cert-manager,%20by%20setting%20the%20webhook.hostNetwork%20key%20to%20true%20on%20your%20deployment,%20or,%20if%20using%20Helm,%20configuring%20it%20in%20your%20values.yaml%20file.%20%20Note%20that%20running%20on%20the%20host%20network%20will%20necessitate%20changing%20the%20webhook%27s%20port;%20see%20the%20warning%20at%20the%20top%20of%20the%20page%20for%20details.).
and change the default port from 10250 to something else ( i used 10255 ) just make sure you replace all instances. good luck

Answer (score 0):

You may have a network policies issue ! have any cluster restrictions ? If yes you may need to add something like that:

```yaml
---
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: allow-cert-manager-resolver-reverse
  namespace: cert-manager
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: cert-manager
  egress:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          acme.cert-manager.io/http01-solver: true
---
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: allow-cert-manager-resolver
  namespace: "{{namespace}}"
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      acme.cert-manager.io/http01-solver: "true"
  ingress:
    - ports:
      - port: 8089
        protocol: TCP
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          app.kubernetes.io/instance: cert-manager
```

Answer (score -3):

I do this it, and work for me.

helm install 
cert-manager jetstack/cert-manager 
--namespace cert-manager 
--create-namespace 
--version v1.8.0 
--set webhook.securePort=10260

source: https://hackmd.io/@maelvls/debug-cert-manager-webhook

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)